# Using Firestore emulator for unit testing in a packaged project

Tags: unit-testing, go, google-cloud-firestore, integration-testing

I am trying to mock a firestore local client to run my unit integration tests in my Go project, but I have packaged the project so that, firestore is initialized in a separate package and used throughout the other packages.

So I am kind of confused about where should I define the local firestore client and the `TestMain(m *testing.M)` function. Below is the basic idea of my file structure.

```
main.go
main_test.go (This could also need firestore local connection)
pkg
|____datastore (where firestore clients are defined)
     |___datastore.go
     |___testing.go (I intended to have my TestMain(m *testing.M) function to run the emulator)
     |___ .....
|____pkg2
     |___myfile.go (go file that I use the firestore client to deal with firestore db)
     |___myfile_test.go ( tests I am going to write that I need to use the local emulator)
     |___ .....
```

So I am wondering how this kind of a testing can be achieved. Waitng for help. Also I got the idea of firestore emulator using this [link](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2020/03/04/unit-testing-with-firestore-emulator-and-go)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue. Because go doesn't have a test function that runs before all tests, there's no good way to set up the emulator before running.

There are two options from what I've seen: (I would love to hear more suggestions).

1. Use the `emulators:exec scriptpath` command from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure. This will run the emulator and then run your script, in this case, your go tests.
2. Write a utility function that initializes the firebase emulator. Then, in every package, use the `TestMain` function to set up the firebase environment. This will enable you to run every test individually but fail when running your entire test suite. The solution for the last problem is to remove parallel processing for your go suite, something like this: `go test ./... -v -race -p 1`
3. Run the emulator externally, outside of the tests, and then run the tests. The downside to this approach is that you have to make sure the emulator is manually running before starting the test suite. You would also have to clean up after every test which might become annoying.

I went with the second solution, but you will have to ensure the emulator is not already running and terminates it after every package test.

so something like this:

```golang
shutdownCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("lsof -i tcp:%d | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9", firestorePort))
```

Then you will need to run the emulator:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("firebase", "emulators:start", "--only", "firestore")
```

You'll have to listen for the standard output of the emulator and parse it to check when:

1. emulator is ready
2. emulator could not start
3. emulator stopped

Then, after the emulator started, you can run

```golang
result = m.Run()
```

Which will run the test suite of the current package.

Finally, after tests are done for the package, you would have to send a signal to the emulator to shutdown (SIGINT):

```golang
syscall.Kill(cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGINT)
```

I considered releasing the solution open source but didn't have enough time to make it nice. Feel free to reach out if you want me to share the full solution with you

Comment: @JimB `TestMain` is only running before the package tests, not before `ALL` tests.

Comment: thanks, missed the multiple packages aspect